# Modify measure to only affect Totals in Matrix Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to PBI Desktop & StackOverflow in general. If anyone can help me out with this situation, much appreciated.

I created this matrix table where it displays the count of male/female students in a student division (I just made up these numbers). I created a measure called 'Percentage of males' that calculates the number of male students and divide it by the total number of students in each division.

The calculation wasn't, the hard part, but the issue is when I place the measure in the values field. Instead of just wanting to show it for totals only, it appears under the female & male subcategories as well (refer to image). Does anyone know if there's a way to modify the measure so that it only affects the total?

I tried looking at some videos, but couldn't really find one for this situation.

```
Proportion of Males = DIVIDE(
COUNTX(
FILTER(sheet2, Sheet[M/F]="M"), Sheet2[M/F], COUNTA(Sheet2[M/F]), 0)
```

[image: reference image]

Comment: Why you just not use a table instead of matrix?

Comment: Hi Karish here. Thanks for taking a look at this. I think it's possible to do with a table, but on cases when I do have to use a matrix instead of table, how can I modify my measure? Let's say if I have to use a matrix, how can I do it?

Comment: This is a calculation for total; you can try pack your statement into IF using dax function HASONEVALUE. Total has many value for your [M/F].

https://dax.guide/hasonevalue/

something like:

if( HASONEVALUE(Sheet2[M/F]), BLANK(), <yourCalculation> )

Comment: I tried out the measure that you mention, and I got closer to my expected result. Now the 100% column is now completely gone. Do you know if there's a way I can hide these two blank columns indicated in this image provided? I provided my expected results in this image here if it helps out

file:///C:/Users/karis/Desktop/Measure.pdf